# Redux - mapStateToProps not working (React-Native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I am learning Redux and can't seem to get state to display in my home page. I get the error: 'undefined is not an object, evaluating this.props.titles.allTitles. The error is located in Home created by connect function' Here is the code, let me know if you need any other files. Thank you. I am adding more text to comply with stack overflow, thank you for your help.

home:

````
    import React from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux'

    class Home extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <View>
                    <Text>Redux Test</Text>
                    <Button
                        title='+ new list'
                        onPress={() => 
                            this.props.navigation.navigate('New List')
                        }
                        />

                    <Text>{this.props.titles.allTitles.length}</Text>

                </View>

            )
        }
    }


    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        const { titles } = state
        return { titles }
      };

    export default connect(mapStateToProps) (Home);
    ```
    reducer: 
    ```
    import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

    const INITIAL_STATE = {
        allTitles: []
    };

    const tagReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case 'NEW_LIST':
                return {
                    ...state,
                    allTitles: [...state.allTitles, action.payload.title]
                }


            default: 
                return state;
        }

    };

    const reducers = combineReducers({
        tagReducer
    })

    export default reducers;
    ```
    import React from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, TextInput } from 'react-native';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { newList } from '../store/tagActions';


    class List extends React.Component {
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                title: ''
            }
        }


        render() {
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.title}
                        placeholder='add Title..' 
                        onChangeText={text => this.setState( {title: text} ) }
                    />

                    <Button
                        title='done'
                        onPress={() => {
                            this.props.newList(this.state.title)
                            }
                        }
                    />

                    <Text>{this.state.title}</Text>

                </View>
            )
        }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        const { allTitles } = state
        return { allTitles }
      };



      export default connect(mapStateToProps, { newList }) (List);
````

Answer (score 1):

In your reducer, you have the following -

`allTitles: [...state.allTitles, action.payload.title]`

When you do, I don't see `title` in the redux state.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    const { titles } = state
    return { titles }
  };
```

You need to do

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    const { allTitles } = state
    return { allTitles }
  };
```

Then do `{this.props.allTitles.length}` inside the render statement

Answer (score 1):

Getting Redux setup can be pretty tricky in my opinion. After taking a look at your code I created a small React-Native project and setup Redux as closely as possibly to what you described in your question. Hopefully my answer helps. Please note that all three the files in my answer (App.js, Home.js, & titleReducer.js) are contained in the same directory.

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';

import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';

import titleReducer from './titleReducer';

// React-Redux
import { 
  createStore,
  combineReducers,
} from 'redux';
import { 
  connect, 
  Provider 
} from 'react-redux';

// Import Components (Screens)
import Home from './Home';

// Intialize Redux Store
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  titles: titleReducer
});
const store = createStore(rootReducer);

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Home/>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

**titleReducer.js**

```
const initialState = {
  allTitles: [],
};

const titleReducer = (state, action) => {

  // check for state undefined to prevent 
  // redux from crashing app on load
  if (typeof state === 'undefined') {
    return {...initialState};
  }

  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TITLE':
      const newState = {...state};
      const newTitle = action.payload;
      newState.allTitles.push(newTitle);
      return newState;
    default:
      return {...state};
  }

  // If none of the conditions above are true,
  // simply return a copy of the current state
  return {...state};
};

export default titleReducer;
```

**Home.js**

```
import React from 'react';

import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';

import { 
  connect, 
  Provider 
} from 'react-redux';

function randomTitle() {
  return Math.random().toString();
}

class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Redux Test</Text>
        <Button 
          title="Add Title"
          onPress={ () => this.props.addTitle(randomTitle()) }/>
        <Text>{this.props.titles.allTitles.length}</Text> 
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    addTitle: (payload) => dispatch({type: 'ADD_TITLE', payload: payload}),
  };
};
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { 
    titles: state.titles,
  };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

Comment: Thanks for doing that. Helps a lot to see how you would do it. I still seem to be missing something. It says the error is located at Home (created by connect function) if that helps. I'm also going to update the post to include the file I am performing the dispatch from.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've forgot to define a store for your app. Go to your root class (app.js or something) and define your reducers to your store:

```
const store = createStore(tagReducer)
```

or if you have multiple reducers you can combine them in one line:

```
const store = createStore(combineReducers({
   tag: tagReducer,
   someOther: otherReducer
}));
```

Hope that it fixes your problem.